# How to see the complete list of methods in a ExtJs class

Tags: javascript, extjs

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.menu.Item-method-onClick

If you scroll down to the Methods
Defined By
Instance methods section you can find onClick.

If you hover over Methods onClick does not show.

Is there an issue with the doc here or do I need some schooling on how to read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to change the default configuration of the docs, at the top right there is a control "show" you should mark as selected private and protected**  [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ8ql.png)